# Debug PseudoConstant

Tags: civicase, activities, error, debugging

I noticed recently under my Drupal "recent logged messages", I've been getting errors logged with the message:

"Deprecated function, use CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::getKey Array ( [civi.tag] => deprecated )"

AND

Error: [] operator not supported for strings in CRM_Utils_Recent::del() (line 173 of C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Utils\Recent.php).

What does this mean? I am on Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 4.7.22. I think this seems to appear when I'm trying to delete a case or delete any activities. I see the spinner keep running forever and just hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to the first one its a little bit misleading the actual thing is another function has been marked as deprecated and calls to that function should be refactored to use CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::getKey this is the related issue  https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20424

In regards to the 2nd issue i have opened a ticket here https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20939 and submitted a pull request here https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10721 to fix the issue.

If you can it would be helpful if you could add a ticket on the first issue in the JIRA and reference CRM-20424 in the ticket.

Seamus

Comment: Sure, I'll add a ticket on JIRA for the PseudoConstant.

RE: the second issue, thank you! I can confirm that your CRM-20939 Fix worked on CRM/Utils/Recent.php. I'm able to delete the case now. Whew, thanks!!